# Building Qt app on mac os x for deployment

Tags: qt

I am building Qt app for deployment on mac os x 10.7.2 with Qt 4.8.3. my app is 'Test.app' 
after running otool -L Test.app it is giving path as below.

```
QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui 
QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore
```

I have copied two QtGui.framework and QtCore.framework to Test.app

then i used following commands

```
install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore
Test.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore

install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui
Test.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui.
```

then used change command like this

```
install_name_tool -change /Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore
@executable_path/../Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore
Test.app/Contents/MacOs/Test

install_name_tool -change /Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui
@executable_path/../Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui
Test.app/Contents/MacOs/Test
```

After that if i will otool -L Test.app still it is giving previous path.

is there any mistake while running commands.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it manually. Use the tool `macdeployqt` that comes with Qt: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-mac.html#the-mac-deployment-tool